# How can I lookup properties in a slurped file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

According to the ansible documentation, I can use [slurp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html) to read a remote file.

I have a java properties file on a remote host that I want to slurp so I did:

```
- name slurp xyz properties
  slurp:
    src: /some/path/on/the/remote/my.properties
  register: myprops

- debug:
    msg: "{{ myprops['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

If I do that I get the content.

Now I want to use that conent in ansible. E.g. through a [`lookup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html). Something like this:

```
{{lookup('somePropertyInPropertiesFile', myprops['content'])}}
```

But this doesn't work since the lookup module only allows lookup in files.

**How can I pass the slurped file to the lookup?**

I'm using ansible 2.9.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given ansible lookups work on the control host, you can also get a file `from remote to local` using [`fetch`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html) module. Then use [`ini`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/ini.html) lookup to read a specific property from the properties file.

I couldn't test the code but something like below should work.

```yaml
- name: Fetch my properties
  fetch:
    src: /some/path/on/the/remote/my.properties
    dest: /tmp/
    flat: yes

- debug: 
    msg: "content is {{ lookup('ini', 'content type=properties file=/tmp/my.properties') }}"
```

`flat: yes` will copy the file under /tmp without creating a dir with hostname in the given destination dir which is the default behavior. This might be useful if you have a single host or do not care if the file gets overwritten.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped that I can just use slurp and omit a temporary file, because the remote file might contain security sensitive information. Thus I wanted to hold it only in memory for the time ansible executes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Moon is correct, but I want to add more details about java property files.

It seems that ansible can only hanlde simple java property files like:

```
user.name=robert
user.pass=somerandompassword
```

But the java properties file format also allowes values to span serveral lines, e.g.

```
targetCities=\
    Detroit,\
    Chicago,\
    Los Angeles
```

When you have entries like this, ansible doesn't parse them correctly. Ansible's result is:

```
ok: [..............] => {
    "msg": "content is \\\nDetroit,\\\nChicago,\\\nLos Angeles"
}
```

But the java [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-) documentation say:

> Properties are processed in terms of lines. There are two kinds of line, natural lines and logical lines. A natural line is defined as a line of characters that is terminated either by a set of line terminator characters (\n or \r or \r\n) or by the end of the stream. A natural line may be either a blank line, a comment line, or hold all or some of a key-element pair. **A logical line** holds all the data of a key-element pair, which may be **spread out across several adjacent natural lines** by **escaping** the line terminator sequence with a **backslash** character .

Thus

```
targetCities=\
    Detroit,\
    Chicago,\
    Los Angeles
```

should be equivalent to

```
targetCities=Detroit,Chicago,Los Angeles
```

which is not the case as explained above.

**EDIT**

Sadly some property files, like tomcat's catalina.properties, can not be parsed at all.

```
fatal: [..............]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running 
the lookup plugin 'ini'. Error was a <class 'ConfigParser.ParsingError'>, original 
message: File contains parsing errors: <???>\n\t[line 35]: u'org.apache.jasper.,org.apache.naming.,org.apache.tomcat.\\r\\n'\n\t[line 110]:
...
```

Comment: Yeah, basically anything after `=` is parsed as a string with char escaping. If multiline then the carriage return is also added as if it's a multiline yaml string. Just as a workaround, escaped backslash and newline characters can be replaced using replace filter `replace('\\\n', '')`. Not that elegant but would do the job I guess.